# creating new worksheet from workbook in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

```
If WSheetFound Then 'if WSheetFound = True

    'copy and paste the record to the relevant worksheet, in the next available row
    internal_numberName.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(internal_numberName.Value).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

    Else 'if WSheetFound = False
    
    Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)) ' insert a new Worksheet
    NewWSheet.Name = internal_numberName 'named after that branch
    
    DataWSheet.Range("A1", DataWSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A1") 'and copy the headings to it
    
    internal_numberName.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 10).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A2") ' then copy and paste the record to i
    
End If
```

while Heading is getting created, its failing when trying to add content from A2, can anyone help me on this

Comment: "failing" is not a useful description of what actually happens when you run your code.  It's much easier here if you tell us the exact problem.

Comment: Getting Runtime error 1004 (Application denied or object defined error

Comment: What's the cell address of `internal_numberName` when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a New Worksheet If It Doesn't Exist

- The only error I could produce was when `internal_numberName` contained a number, then the first line in the 'If' statement would fail which is easily avoided with `...Worksheets(CStr(internal_numberName.Value))...`.
- These 'unexplained' errors often happen when there is an `On Error Resume Next` placed somewhere before the code. If that is the case, remove it because it 'hides' one or several errors previously occurring.
- If the posted code doesn't help, you will need to reveal more of the code, best all of it.
- The following code eliminates the need for a function or whatever you're using to determine if the destination worksheet already exists.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    
    Dim DataWSheet As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Set DataWSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim internal_numberName As Range
    Set internal_numberName = DataWSheet.Range("D2")
    
    ' The above is irrelevant for your code, it's just for testing purposes.
    
    Dim NewName As String: NewName = CStr(internal_numberName.Value)
    
    Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet ' Destination Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim dfCell As Range ' Destination First Cell
    
    ' Reference the destination worksheet.
    
    ' Attempt to reference the worksheet.
    Set NewWSheet = Nothing ' necessary if in a loop
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping
        Set NewWSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(NewName)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' stop error trapping
    
    If NewWSheet Is Nothing Then ' worksheet doesn't exist
        Set NewWSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets _
            .Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        NewWSheet.Name = NewName
        DataWSheet.Range("A1", DataWSheet.Cells(1, DataWSheet.Columns.Count) _
            .End(xlToLeft)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A1")
    'Else ' worksheet exists; do nothing
    End If
    
    ' Copy
    
    Set srg = internal_numberName.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 10)
    Set dfCell = NewWSheet.Cells(NewWSheet.Rows.Count, "A") _
        .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
End Sub
```